# python: how to create persistent in-memory structure for debugging

Tags: python, debugging, persistence, python-3.x

**[Python 3.1]**

My program takes a long time to run just because of the `pickle.load` method on a huge data structure. This makes debugging very annoying and time-consuming: every time I make a small change, I need to wait for a few minutes to see if the regression tests passed.

I would like replace `pickle` with an in-memory data structure.

I thought of starting a python program in one process, and connecting to it from another; but I am afraid the inter-process communication overhead will be huge.

Perhaps I could run a python function from the interpreter to load the structure in memory. Then as I modify the rest of the program, I can run it many times (without exiting the interpreter in between). This seems like it would work, but I'm not sure if I will suffer any overhead or other problems.

Comment: Are you also modifying the rest of the program in the interpreter? If not, maybe module loading will be an issue.

Comment: Are you using `cPickle`? Which version of Python?

Comment: @Danosaure I'm modifying the rest of the program in an editor outside the interpreter. So I guess it won't work as I hoped; perhaps there's some way to force the interpreter to reload the modules if they are changed?

Comment: @Greg Newgill I'm using Python 3 (just edited my question to say so). I'm using pickle; somehow I didn't find cPickle in ActivePython 3.1???

Comment: I'm not sure whether I'm understanding correctly but Python does have a reload function to reload an imported module. (http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html ctrl+f reload)

Comment: @Greg Newgill ahhh in Python 3, cPickle module is gone; it's treated as an implementation detail, and pickle automatically uses it if it can.

Comment: @Rob Lourens Yes, it seems perfect for my needs. Didn't know about it!

Comment: @max: Right, that's why the version of Python is important. How big is "huge"?

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: the pickle'd file is in the range of 0.5-2 GB; so it's big enough to take time to read from disk, but small enough to easily fit into physical memory (without paging).

Comment: What are you pickling that's so big? Sounds like maybe you should use a database?

Comment: @Falmarri: Even if I switch to using a database, the original question will still remain: how do I keep it persistent in memory?

Comment: If you were reading from a database you probably wouldn't need to keep it persistent since it doesn't have to deserialize it every time. However, you CAN set up an sqlite database in memory.

Comment: @Falmarri: I would have an in-memory database in sqlite. However, I won't be able to access it once I rerun my program in a different process (which is what I'm doing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mmap`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/mmap.html) to open a view on the same file in multiple processes, with access at almost the speed of memory once the file is loaded.

Comment: While it still makes me spend time to re-parse the file into the data structure, it's a very interesting feature. However, reading `mmap` docs, I don't see how I can use it: when I make changes to one of the modules and run the program again, the new process won't be a child process; how can it see the `mmap` object then?

Comment: Opening the same file in `mmap()` will show the same view on the file.

Comment: I guess this is the only solution that doesn't require me to start the program in the interpreter. I still prefer the interpreter solution for my needs - assuming it has no hidden problems! - because it allows me to persist the data structure rather than just raw file data.

Answer (score 0):

First you can pickle different parts of the hole object using this method:

```
# gen_objects.py

import random
import pickle

class BigBadObject(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.a_dictionary={}
      for x in xrange(random.randint(1, 1000)):
         self.a_dictionary[random.randint(1,98675676)]=random.random()
      self.a_list=[]
      for x in xrange(random.randint(1000, 10000)):
         self.a_list.append(random.random())
      self.a_string=''.join([chr(random.randint(65, 90)) 
                        for x in xrange(random.randint(100, 10000))])

if __name__=="__main__":
   output=open('lotsa_objects.pickled', 'wb')
   for i in xrange(10000):
      pickle.dump(BigBadObject(), output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
   output.close()
```

Once you generated the BigFile in various separate parts you can read it with a python program with several running at the same time reading each one different parts.

```
# reader.py

from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue, Empty
import cPickle as pickle
import time
import operator

from gen_objects import BigBadObject

class Reader(Thread):
   def __init__(self, filename, q):
      Thread.__init__(self, target=None)
      self._file=open(filename, 'rb')
      self._queue=q
   def run(self):
      while True:
         try:
            one_object=pickle.load(self._file)
         except EOFError:
            break
         self._queue.put(one_object)

class uncached(object):
   def __init__(self, filename, queue_size=100):
      self._my_queue=Queue(maxsize=queue_size)
      self._my_reader=Reader(filename, self._my_queue)
      self._my_reader.start()
   def __iter__(self):
      while True:
         if not self._my_reader.is_alive():
            break
         # Loop until we get something or the thread is done processing.
         try:
            print "Getting from the queue. Queue size=", self._my_queue.qsize()
            o=self._my_queue.get(True, timeout=0.1) # Block for 0.1 seconds 
            yield o
         except Empty:
            pass
      return

# Compute an average of all the numbers in a_lists, just for show.
list_avg=0.0
list_count=0

for x in uncached('lotsa_objects.pickled'):
   list_avg+=reduce(operator.add, x.a_list)
   list_count+=len(x.a_list)

print "Average: ", list_avg/list_count
```

This way of reading the pickle file will take 1% of the time it takes in the other way. This is because you are running 100 parallel threads at the same time.

Comment: It seems to me that threads would collide while trying to read from disk; while my Python program uses only 1 out of 8 CPU threads, the disk I/O is already at full capacity. In other words, I don't think I can read from disk any faster by having multiple threads do it.